How to get block number from `nfts`
Is it possible to get blocknumber or created timestamp from this query?
await api.query.nfts.item.keys(collectionId)


There isn't a directly way to do this.

Do you have any other workaround for getting a block number from the list of NFTs from a specific collection?

There isn't a direct way to do this.
Here are my suggestions:

Monitor an event and check the timestamp of the event's block (if such an event exists).
Monitor an extrinsic and check the timestamp of its block, ensuring that the extrinsic was successful and modified the storage.

These methods are quite unstable, so I'm not certain they will work as expected in your situation.
